# Can I get Microphone Input AND PC audio BOTH through Headphones without Delay?

Tags: microphone, monitoring, fl-studio

I am trying to get both my PC's audio and my microphone input to go into my headphones so I can hear them both; I have thus far managed to monitor the microphone with FL Studio, so I hear that in my headphones, but now my PC audio plays through my screen speakers and I can't find a way to get it to play through my headphones. Any solutions to this?

Comment: Are you using an audio interface? If so, what's the brand & model?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve it! There seems to be very little information available online on how to do this, which is odd because I'd expect it's quite common amongst YouTubers. Here is exactly what I did.

- Download and Install FL Studio, ensuring ASIO4ALL is installed as part of the installation as usual.
- Download and install Voicemeeter Banana - http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter/banana.htm
- Restart
- Open Voicemeeter Banana
- For Hardware Out, select ASIO4ALL v2
- For Hardware Input 1 select your microphone
- Click Menu -> System settings / Options
- Where it says "Buffering ASIO:", change that to 128
- Where it says "Engine Mode" change that to "Swift"
- Close settings
- On Hardware Input 1, adjust the two knobs until it sounds right to you
- In Master Section, for the first thing, click EQ so it's blue, then right click EQ, then adjust it until it sounds good to you
- Tada

From start to finish it took me like 2 days of research to get my mic and PC audio both going through my headphones with minimal delay. Hopefully you don't have to now :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to suggest this is purely for hearing purposes, not for any recording purposes. If that's the case, you just need to go to:-

**Control Panel > Sound > Recording > Right-click on your Mic Input > Properties > Listen > Listen to this Device** You can then select your Headphones / Default Output Device etc, and your Mic Input will play back through that along with your system audio.

[image]

Comment: @Warbinator Ah ok then, fair enough. In theory if you just capture your Default Output in your recording session with the above ticked then this would work too, but if you're experiencing a substantial amount of latency with your soundcard/mobo, then it'll definitely be too distracting making it nearly impossible to speak! I'm glad you've found a method that works for your setup though, and good job in persevering with it until you found it!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works. I would like to make this post for others who may still be digging in forums for a solution. I was able to find on Amazon an affordable [USB audio interface](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005EHILV4) that allowed me to monitor my voice with zero latency, adjust the volume, and even play around with EQ settings. It only costed about 60 USD. If you have a headset that has a separate mic and audio jack 3.5 mm, you can simply plug them in the dedicated port on the Audio Interface. If you have a headset that has only one jack 3.5 mm that combines both Mic and Audio, you will need a [splitter cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00PYZ2BT4)  (You can find it as cheap as 5 USD on amazon). This set up can be cheaper than headsets that integrate mic monitoring. 
[image]

Comment: Just to be sure, you can also listen to the PC output as well along with your own voice, right? I want to _add_ real time monitoring to voice calls. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try setting your mic built-in interface as a default playback device. Do the same with headphones (it depends what is showing up, there may be a mic's interface, a headphone, or both). If that didn't work, try disabling your PC speakers and rebooting programs which play audio (browser or media player, or whatever).

Try also reinstalling drivers (if your mic needs them)

Well, if this won't work, it's possible that your mic's built-in audio interface just can't work with two or more apps at the same time, which is a pretty common thing. You can't do anything about it without buying another gear

Answer (score -1):

To mix your MIC and PC Sound (possibly for Skype), please follow Voicemeeter User Manual step by step until use case #1: http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter/Voicemeeter_UserManual.pdf

Comment: If the link to the user manual changes or the contents of the user manual change, this answer won't provide any information about solving the problem.  If you can include the key details in your answer, it would greatly improve the answer.